# Do existing laws bar cyberprostitution?

Tags: united-states, oregon, prostitution

Do existing laws bar cyberprostitution?

I’m putting this in for Oregon, but I’m also curious about other jurisdictions.

There have been numerous advances in “teledildonics." Let’s just say for the sake of argument that this technology is perfected, and two people can put on suits and have sex over the Internet.

Do existing laws make it illegal to charge for cybersex?

Follow up question: If it is illegal, what if the other person is in Nevada in a county where it’s legal? Are both parties breaking the law or only the one in Washington?

Please note that I currently have no plans to engage in this activity personally, regardless of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could conceivably be a pornography crime, particularly if a participant is a minor, but there is no precedent for considering remote interaction involving sexual content, in the nature of a camgirl performance with a particularly vivid virtual reality user interface, to be prostitution.

Answer (score 0):

[In Oregon](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/167.007) it is probably not a crime, because it constitutes [sexual conduct](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/167.002), which "means sexual intercourse or oral or anal sexual intercourse". The law does not define "sexual intercourse", and it is well known that there are diverging schools of thought as to what counts as "sexual intercourse". Washington does define [sexual intercourse](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.44.010) by saying that it "has its ordinary meaning", but clarifies (?) that it "occurs upon any penetration".